Help with texbook question on probabilities: Smoking, Drinking, and Lung Cancer in Men Over 50 Years Old
I need help with this problem about probabilities ..
I am stuck with the first question

The age of the male population follows a normal distribution with an
arithmetic mean of 39 years and a standard deviation of 17 years. A
recent study on smoking in men over 50 years old reveals that 38% of
those who smoke more than 10 cigarettes (an average pack) per day die
from lung cancer, while only 5% of those who smoke less than that
amount die from the same cause. In a representative group of men of
any age, it is found that 31% smoke, 37% regularly consume alcoholic
beverages, and 40% do neither. Taking into account that only 6% of
smokers consume more than half a pack daily... 1. What is the
probability that a man is over 50 years old and also smokes and
drinks? 2. What is the probability that in a group of 1200 male
smokers over 50 years old, more than 60 die from lung cancer?

I was able to calculate the probability of being older than 50 using excel function 1-DISTR.NORM.N(50;39;17;TRUE) which returns 0.26 as well as the probability of smoking (0.60 * 0.31=0.19), probability of drinking (0.37 * 0.0.60=0.22), probability of drinking and smoking as 0.22 * 0.19= 0.04 but I am not able to answer the questions .. the results are said to be  0.0206 for the probability that a man is older than 50 and also smokes and drinks while 0.0041 for the second question and I don't know where they come from .. can anyone help with this?

Start by critically examining what might justify multiplying the probabilities of drinking and smoking.  Make sure you utilize all the information about drinking and smoking.

Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you
is grounds for closing.
